# SCCM- pause all active deploymetns

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

I got the request to pause all active deployments. There would be around 200+ applications are active at the moment.

How can i pause all the active deployments.

I don't want to do it manually one by one.

I thought about below options but not sure these will work or not.

```
1- Stop sccm executive service
2- Stop sms agent host service
3- Create duplicate collection and delete all the members from original collection
```

Any thing else i can do?

Please advise.

Edit:

Can i use maintenance window in this scenario to pause the deployments.